# Jenkins Pipeline withCredentials secret file odd behavior

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenksin v2.5.0 with [Credentials](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) plugin v 2.1.16 and [CredentialsBinding](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) plugin v1.13 (both latest available) and while it appears to work as intended, it exhibits and odd repeating behavior as I continue to re-run my pipeline.

The following pipeline syntax is in use:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: '<credID>', variable: 'KEY_FILE')]) {
       ...steps here create ${workspace}/ssh script using KEY_FILE...
       sh(script: "docker exec ${containerName} /bin/bash -c 'cd ${entryPoint} && GIT_SSH='${workspace}/ssh' git fetch --tags --progress git@gitserver.com:${group}/${project}.git +refs/h eads/${branch}:refs/remotes/origin/${branch}'")
} //credentials
```

It evaluates as expected and is functional, as shown here:

```
    [Build] Running shell script
    + docker exec <container> /bin/bash -c 'cd /<buildRoot>/build && GIT_SSH=/<workspace>/ssh git fetch --tags --progress git@gitsserver.com:<group>/<project>.git +refs/heads/staging:refs/remotes/origin/staging'
    Warning: Identity file /<workspace>/<job>@tmp/secretFiles/a36b7edb-2914-419a-8be0-478603d1b031/keyfile.txt not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from gitserver.com port 22:2: Too many authentication failures for git
Connection to gitsserver.com closed by remote host.
Warning: Identity file /<workspace>/<job>@tmp/secretFiles/ccb1e11c-18f5-4697-b5c1-e4514c1ab1c7/keyfile.txt not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

*** The part where it states that it can't find the file during the git operation (that is using SSH underneath) is what continues to repeat, each time with a different secret files GUID in the path (shown above are two of the repeats).  The underlying implementation appears to implement a loop of sorts over the 'git fetch' command, trying a new credentials path each time.

Both how/why Jenkins:
1) Creates these new paths each time
2) Knows to keep looping over the single failed git command until it finally delivers the secret file that enables the authentication and git succeeds
are mysteries to me.

Any insight would be appreciated.

PS> I'm already aware that newer versions of git not (yet) available in my environment have different methods for providing SSH options.  I'd like this question to focus on the odd withCredentials behavior.

PPS> I've also already tried higher level constructs for the pipeline including at least the 'git' SCM plugin specialization and the 'docker' node type with it's "inside()" functionality, but many iterations of those constructs always left me with some oddity that, again, is not the focus of this question.

Comment: Not sure if it’s related but I just raised https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/INFRA-1376

Comment: You are certain that the secret files are in there correctly, yes?

Comment: @kirkpatt Yes, because it eventually succeeds, the specific problem is that the retry count seems to be ever-increasing

Comment: I'm not sure it is clear how you use the KEY_FILE in the 'docker exec' command, and - more unclear - whether the docker container see the file inside of it since I don't see a mounting of it to the container.

Comment: @yorammi Sorry, I had edited for brevity.   The docker container is created with two "-v" arguments to mount the Jenkins workspace.   The docker container is created and mounts those locations prior to withCredentials delivering files there, but they do become visible.

Comment: The docker -v locations are of folders or of the file? you should not mount to a file if it is the case.
Anyway, what about creating the ssh command inside the container instead on the Jenkins master/slave? it might be a better usage.

Comment: @yorammi The container mounts are at the Jenkins workspace folder level.   I see your point about generating the wrapper script inside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is not a problem with Jenkins or any of the plugins at all.

The temporary script that was written to the Jenkins workspace was continuously being appended to, meaning it was the source of all the invalid secret file paths and the "loop"...the last command in that script would always be the one with the correct path and it would succeed.